# Zend_Gdata exception.

Tags: php, zend-framework, gmail-imap, zend-gdata

I am using Zend api to grab user gmail inbox. I am getting the following error:

```
[Fri Mar 23 14:12:10 2012] [error] [client 119.152.61.10] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Mail_Storage_Exception' with message 'cannot change folder, maybe it does not exist' in /var/www/vhosts/eblogs.co.uk/httpdocs/frostbox/xoauth-php-samples/Zend/Mail/Storage/Imap.php:467
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/eblogs.co.uk/httpdocs/frostbox/xoauth-php-samples/Zend/Mail/Storage/Imap.php(248): Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap->selectFolder('INBOX')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/eblogs.co.uk/httpdocs/frostbox/xoauth-php-samples/myinbox.php(139): Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap->__construct(Object(Zend_Mail_Protocol_Imap))
#2 {main}
Next exception 'Zend_Mail_Storage_Exception' with message 'cannot select INBOX, is this a valid transport?' in /var/www/vhosts/eblogs.co.uk/httpdocs/frostbox/xoauth-php-samples/Zend/Mail/Storage/Imap.php:254
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/eblogs.co.uk/httpdocs/frostbox/xoauth-php-samples/myinbox.php(139): Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap->__construct(Object(Zend_Mail_Protocol_Imap))
#1 {main}
thrown in /var/www/vhosts/eblogs.co.uk/httpdocs/frostbox/xoauth-php-samples/Zend/Mail/Storage/Imap.php on line 254 


Zend_Mail_Storage_Exception' with message 'cannot select INBOX, is this a valid transport?'
```